# Butterknife Fragment Injecting Views Not Working?

Tags: android, android-listview, butterknife

Can anyone explain why my View element (ListView) is `null` with the following code:

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    @InjectView(R.id.news_listView) ListView lv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (lv == null) {
            UIHelper.showAlert("null?");
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there something wrong with the library, because I pasted the example code to my app to get it working, but it's not working here... Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you setup your IDE?

> IDE CONFIGURATION
>
> Some IDEs require additional configuration in order to enable
>   annotation processing.
>
> IntelliJ IDEA — If your project uses an external configuration (like a
>   Maven pom.xml) then annotation processing should just work. If not,
>   [try manual configuration](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-idea.html).
>
> [Eclipse — Set up manual configuration](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html)

Usually this means that the annotation processor didn't do its work. That might be due to misconfiguration or random problems with the IDE. In my experience, every now and then I had to clean the project and build everything again.

Comment: Not working for me =( I followed the steps from the link for Eclipse, but from step # 4 _"Make sure that the .apt_generated/ folder is in your project root."_ - I do not see any folder named `apt-generated` in my project root, and the errors don't go away.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
...

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}  

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
...
```